# Return type interface for the method implemented, Ienumerator

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, collections

the GetEnumerator return type is the interface itself i.e Ienumerable, wondering what it means when an interface can be a method's return type; specially when its defined in that interface.

```
Ienumerator enum = arrayList.GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: It means that what is returned must implement IEnumerator or whatever interface.

Comment: Thanks ben, you surely know way ahead than me, just wondering i dont see IEnumerator being implemented in code, and does that mean GetEnumerator is returning a class which has implemented IEnumerator.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: fabulous,one last doubt , there is a possibility that GetEnumerator must have implemented more interfaces and methods, so what it returns must be a class bigger than signatures defined in IEnumerator, or does that mean its written like Public Static IEnumerator GetEnumerator() there

Comment: so if not, what extra methods GetEnumerator is coming back with, cant be used then as signatures defined in Ienumerator can be used on enum as suboperations.

Comment: GetEnumerator is a method returning an IEnumerator, which is an object of a type that implements IEnumerator. You can access methods defined in the IEnumerator interface through enum.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly. ArrayList doesn't implement **IEnumerator**, rather **IEnumerable**.

```
public class ArrayList : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable
```

IEnumerable

```
public interface IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}
```

Edit:

IEnumerator has one simple responsibility.

> Supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection.

ArrayList's responsibility is different

> Implements the IList interface using an array whose size is
>   dynamically increased as required.

May be this is required for maintaining of SRP.

ArrayList's implementation of GetEnumerator() probably returns implementation of IEnumerable which is aware of implementation details of ArrayList. But concrete type is hidden from the client behind the IEnumerator interface.

Comment: thats correct, but IEnumerator implements IEnumerable, can the return type of a method be an interface,

Comment: Probably IEnumerable::GetEnumerator() simply instantiates concrete type implementing IEnumerator and returns it. It's like a factory.